# How do I make a video iframe object-fit cover inside a div?

Tags: css

I found this JSFiddle which does pretty much exactly what I'm trying to accomplish - https://jsfiddle.net/q1rjg9zd/

Notice that you can resize the output frame, and the video will always fill the entire frame, without any space above/below the video to maintain the 16:9 aspect ratio.

I'm trying to get this exact same effect, except I'd like it to be done in a wrapper div, instead of filling the whole viewport. E.g. I can have a div that is 1000px in height and 500px in width and the video would behave the same as in this example.

I'm really struggling to work out how to do this, since the JSFiddle example uses vw and vh measurements, and when I try to convert those to percentages and fixed pixel measurements, the effect is lost.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.video-background {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}


iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

  @media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
    height: 56.25vw
  }

  @media (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
    width: 177.78vh
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="video-background">
  <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/biWk-QLWY7U?controls=0&showinfo=0&rel=0&autoplay=1&loop=1&mute=1" frameborder="0" controls=0 allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Also looking for a solution to this! I'll let you know if I find something.

Comment: You have the width and height set to 100wh and vh respectively

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution that works for me:

Working examples:

- codepen: https://codepen.io/JamesAlias/pen/QWovwgP
- codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/iframe-video-embed-with-simulated-object-fit-cover-x9nc4j

short explanation:

- Use the `@container` query instead of `@media`
- Set `container-type` to `size`
- Force aspect ratio based on container query width & height (`cqw` & `cqh`)

All major browsers support this by now, but as always: check you requirements: https://caniuse.com/?search=%40container

Hope this helps you out :)

```css
/* 
  Arbitrarily sized & positioned element that will 
  contain the embedded video as background.
*/
.arbitrarily-placed-and-sized-parent-element {
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;

  width: 50vw;
  height: 20vh;
}

/*
  This element contains the iframe, will take it's size from
  it's parent and will behave like an image/video 
  with object-fit: cover.
*/
.video-embed-object-fit-cover {
  position: absolute;

  /* ensure positioning regardless of parent flex settings */
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;

  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  /* important */
  container-type: size;

  /* cut off overflowing video */
  overflow: hidden;
}

.video-embed-object-fit-cover > iframe {
  position: absolute;
  /* keep video centered both vertically and horizontally */
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  /* force aspect ratio based on parent container */
  @container (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
    height: 56.25cqw;
  }

  @container (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
    width: 177.78cqh;
  }

  /* prevent interaction */
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="arbitrarily-placed-and-sized-parent-element">
  <div class="video-embed-object-fit-cover">
    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/biWk-QLWY7U?controls=0&showinfo=0&rel=0&autoplay=1&loop=1&mute=1" frameborder="0" controls="0"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```